# CSS Flex Items Refuses to Change Width

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have 5 flex items within a flex container:

```
<section class="dishesNewest">
    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

**styles.css**

```
.dishesNewest {
  margin: 10rem auto 25rem auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 5%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.newDish {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 150px;
  gap: 2rem 0;
  padding: 8px;
}
```

on a screen width of 800px i want to change the width of each item to something like 40% or 50% so it display as 2 `divs` per row :

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {

  .newDish {
    width: 45%
  }
}
```

but the flex item totally ignores both `width` and `flex-basis`, and it doesnt matter if using pixels, percentage or anything else it doesnt work, why is that happening?

Comment: Have you investigated [`flex-wrap: wrap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-wrap) on the parent element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `width` declaration has no effect due to the fact that `min-width` takes precedence over the `width` declaration, and so the elements will be `150px` width instead. You could override this by setting `min-width: 0` in your media query:

```css
.dishesNewest {
  margin: 10rem auto 25rem auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 5%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.newDish {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 150px;
  gap: 2rem 0;
  padding: 8px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .newDish {
    width: 45%;
    min-width: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="dishesNewest">
    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

Then, to display the elements as two per row, consider allowing the flex children to wrap by setting `flex-wrap: wrap` on the flex parent container:

```css
.dishesNewest {
  margin: 10rem auto 25rem auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 5%;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.newDish {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 150px;
  gap: 2rem 0;
  padding: 8px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .newDish {
    width: 45%;
    min-width: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="dishesNewest">
    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flex-wrap` in `.dishesNewest` along with that rule for 800px. If flex-wrap is not set in the flex container it will never wrap.
When 2 containers cannot fit in the same row because of the min-with (150px) they will break in just one column

(I've added colors for visibility purposes)

```css
.dishesNewest {
  margin: 10rem auto 25rem auto;
  display: flex;
  padding: 0 5%;
  justify-content: center;
}

.newDish {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-width: 150px;
  gap: 2rem 0;
  padding: 8px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .dishesNewest {
   flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .newDish {
    width: 45%
  }
}

/* debugging/display containers */
.newDish{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
.newDish a{
 border: 1px solid blue;
}
.newDish h1{
 border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<section class="dishesNewest">
    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="newDish">
      <a href="#"><img src=${e.image} alt="" class="newDishImg lazyLoad" /></a>
      <h1 class="newDishTitle">${e.title}</h1>
    </div>
</section>
```